# Mongoose sub-document insert into another collection while keeping a relationship in the parent schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to do the following and wondering if it is possible with Mongoose:

1. Keep an array of sub-document Id's to easy use mongoose's populate method.
2. Store the sub-document data in another collection

Example:

```
var ParentSchema = new Schema({
    children : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Child' }]
});
mongoose.model('Parent', ParentSchema);

var ChildSchema = new Schema({
    name : { type: String}
});
mongoose.model('Child', ChildSchema);
```

This is what I want my database to look like:

```
Parents
{
    children:[{ObjectId("52856528cb28bdc18acac23a")},{ObjectId("52856528cb28bdc18acac23b")}]
}

Childs
[{
    _id: ObjectId("52856528cb28bdc18acac23a")
    name: "John"
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("52856528cb28bdc18acac23b"),
    name: "bob"
}]
```

I want to easily be able to call populate by doing the following:

```
Parents.find({}).populate(Parents.children).exec();
```

Is the populate method capable of joining an array of data in this way? Also, how would I store the collection of Id's in the parent schema and store the sub document in the child schema (and do this in a way that I can use the populate method later)?

Note that this reference: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html does what I want except that I intend to store the sub-document in another collection NOT as an embedded document.

Thank you in advance

```
var Child = mongoose.model('Child'),
Parent = mongoose.model('Parent');

var parent = new Parent;
var child = new Child({name: "bob"});
child.save(function(err, child){
    parent.children.push(child);
    parent.save();
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code worked:

```
Parents.find({}).populate(children).exec();
```

So it is possible to populate sub documents that are located in seperate collections.

Comment: This is not a sub document. You are talking about ref: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html. Subdocuments are: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html